# Regex to match a string that is not found later in the same line

Tags: regex, string, regex-group

I have several files with imports like,

```
import AudioPlayer from '@module/qwe/zxc/ert-vbn/AudioPlayer';
import VideoPlayer from '@module/qwe/zxc/ert-vbn/VideoPlayer';
import TextModule from '@module/qwe/zxc/ert-vbn/TextModule';
```

but some of the imports do not match the import name with the file name, for example,

```
import PlayerNote from '@module/qwe/zxc/ert-vbn/NotePlayer';
import FileText from '@module/qwe/zxc/ert-vbn/TextFile';
```

I want to create a RegEx to match only the later 2 so that I can fix them.

**How can I RegEx for "a string that is *not* found later in the same line"?**

Answer (score 1):

Use a capture group around the import name, then use a back-reference in a negative lookahead.

```
^import (\w+)(?!.*\1).*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/8VQlbk/1)